# Semicolon in MIN and MAX statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am practicing SQL on DataLemur website and in the Average Post Hiatus problem, the solution given has the following statement to find the MIN/MAX value of a timestamp:

```
MAX(post_date::DATE)
MIN(post_date::DATE)
```

My question is, why there are two colons? Is it used to give a specific format to this field? Can it be said that using colons + DATE we get rid off the decimal part of the date?

If someone has an article about this will be great, didn't find anything related.

I tried just running the query as

```
MAX(post_date)
MIN(post_date)
```

and the result was the whole timestamp which might indicate that colons + DATE change the format but didn't find anything supporting this.

Comment: Not valid syntax in SQL Server. Looks like a `CAST` - e.g. as in Postgresql

Comment: And looking at https://datalemur.com/questions/sql-average-post-hiatus-1 it says "PostgreSQL 14" at the bottom of the code pane